# How can I monitor a JMX based system from a non JMX based client?

Tags: java, weblogic, jmx

I want to monitor a weblogic system which uses JMX via an Erlang client. How can I do this? (Note that I cannot use SMTP as it is disabled and cannot be enabled on the server)

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy [Jolokia](http://www.jolokia.org/) on the application server which exposes your JMX MBeans over an HTTP interface. All you will need to do then from your Erlang client is make HTTP calls and make sense of the JSON output it returns. Make sure you secure the Jolokia deployment so that the world doesn't have access to it, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this nagios plugin ([Jmx4perl](http://labs.consol.de/lang/de/jmx4perl/)) may help you. It has a java web application which has to be deployed in your WebLogic server. With this app you can access the JMX server of your WebLogic with http.

Perhaps your WebLogic has this sort of application already deployed. JBoss has it: [JmxConsole](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JMXConsole)